# White screen after deploying create-react-app which is gone after a refresh

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx, create-react-app

we seem to have a little problem with a create-react-app application we maintain. After each deployment, whether it is the testing environment on Azure or the production environment on AWS, everybody gets a white screen after visiting the page. What is even more puzzling, the white screen is gone after a refresh. The error we are getting is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'     main.13fb6cbd.js:1
```

The webpage is served by nginx, which is running in a Docker Alpine container. Here is the nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;

  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
  #
  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}

# Enable Gzip compressed.
gzip on;

# Enable compression both for HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 (required for CloudFront).
gzip_http_version  1.0;

# Compression level (1-9).
# 5 is a perfect compromise between size and cpu usage, offering about
# 75% reduction for most ascii files (almost identical to level 9).
gzip_comp_level    5;

# Don't compress anything that's already small and unlikely to shrink much
# if at all (the default is 20 bytes, which is bad as that usually leads to
# larger files after gzipping).
gzip_min_length    256;

# Compress data even for clients that are connecting to us via proxies,
# identified by the "Via" header (required for CloudFront).
gzip_proxied       any;

# Tell proxies to cache both the gzipped and regular version of a resource
# whenever the client's Accept-Encoding capabilities header varies;
# Avoids the issue where a non-gzip capable client (which is extremely rare
# today) would display gibberish if their proxy gave them the gzipped version.
gzip_vary          on;

# Compress all output labeled with one of the following MIME-types.
gzip_types
  application/atom+xml
  application/javascript
  application/json
  application/rss+xml
  application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  application/x-font-ttf
  application/x-web-app-manifest+json
  application/xhtml+xml
  application/xml
  font/opentype
  image/svg+xml
  image/x-icon
  text/css
  text/plain
  text/x-component;
# text/html is always compressed by HttpGzipModule
```

The `Dockerfile`:

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node:11-alpine as build

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./
COPY css-vendor-patch ./css-vendor-patch

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
    python make g++

# We need --unsafe-perm for postinstall
RUN npm install --only=production --unsafe-perm
RUN npm install react-scripts -g --silent
RUN npm audit fix --only=prod
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

### STAGE 2: Production Environment ###
FROM nginx:1.15-alpine
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx-react.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And finally the `package.json` configuration:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.5.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.0.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^1.1.0",
    "@vtex/react-csv-parse": "^3.0.2",
    "ajv": "^6.5.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "chartist": "^0.11.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "color": "^3.0.0",
    "coordinate-parser": "^1.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "debounce": "^1.1.0",
    "deep-equal": "^1.0.1",
    "dompurify": "^2.0.8",
    "draft-js": "^0.10.5",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.8.4",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "flat": "^4.1.0",
    "html-react-parser": "^0.4.6",
    "html-to-draftjs": "^1.4.0",
    "html-to-react": "^1.4.2",
    "i18next": "^11.3.3",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^2.2.0",
    "immutable": "3.8.2",
    "jest": "^23.4.2",
    "js-file-download": "^0.4.10",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "jwt-autorefresh": "^0.2.4",
    "material-ui-pickers": "^1.0.0-rc.11",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "notistack": "^0.4.3",
    "object-path": "^0.11.4",
    "qrcode.react": "^0.8.0",
    "query-string": "^5.1.1",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.3.4",
    "react-avatar-editor": "^11.0.6",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.19.1",
    "react-bus": "^1.0.3",
    "react-chartist": "^0.13.1",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.1",
    "react-csv": "^1.0.14",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.13.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^4.2.12",
    "react-easy-print": "^0.6.0-beta.3",
    "react-google-map": "^3.1.1",
    "react-google-maps-loader": "^4.2.3",
    "react-i18next": "^7.7.0",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-pdf": "^3.0.5",
    "react-player": "^1.11.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "react-signature-canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.1",
    "react-smooth-dnd": "^0.8.2",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^0.8.3",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.12.14",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.1",
    "react-webcam": "^1.0.1",
    "recompose": "^0.27.1",
    "source-map-support": "0.4.3",
    "striptags": "2.2.1",
    "typeface-roboto": "0.0.54",
    "vendor-copy": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "postinstall": "vendor-copy"
  },
  "vendorCopy": [
    {
      "from": "css-vendor-patch/supported-value.js",
      "to": "node_modules/css-vendor/lib/supported-value.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

We have tried adding the `homepage` field to the `package.json` with `.` or the URL of the test server but without a luck. We have also tried unregistering the `serviceWorker` which did not work either.
Any advices are welcome.

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: @UzumakiNaruto yes, I found the solution 2 days ago and wanted to post it here, but I forgot. Thanks for the reminder, I already posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was with the `react-scripts` mismatch between `package.json` and `Dockerfile`. This line in the `Dockerfile`

```
RUN npm install react-scripts -g --silent
```

pulled in the the `3.4.1` version and installed it globally whereas in the `package.json` the `1.1.4` was specified. When the

```
RUN npm run build
```

was run, it probably used the `3.4.1` version which was missing some configurations. After updating `react-scripts` to `3.4.1` in `package.json` (and updating/adding its dependencies and creating the necessary configurations) the problem was gone.